# Append record and sync when button click based on Autocomplete value selected

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, synchronization, kendo-ui

I need to append record based on Autocomplete when the button click :
The Autocomplete bind to wcf in remote database. What i need to do is append the record to local database and sync. Please advise what i need proceed. Thank you

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#search").kendoAutoComplete({ 
        minLength: 3, 
        dataTextField: "SDesc", 
        dataValueField: "RefID", 
        template: '${ data.SDesc } ' + '(' + '${ data.SDate }' + ')',

        dataSource: {
            type: "odata",
            serverFiltering: true,
            serverPaging: true,
            pageSize: 20,
            transport: {
                read: "http://localhost:54329/HH_WcfDataService.svc/Product"
            }
        }
    });   

    $('#btnSelect').click(function (e){
        var value = $("#search").data("kendoAutoComplete").value();
    });
});
```

Comment: What exactly you mean by append the record to local database? Do you mean to add more records on the client side which to be used by the AutoComplete

Comment: Hi Pechka, the select value from autocomplete (remote server) need to add to local database.

Comment: or how i can post the selected data value field to controller from View

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually only the Autocomplete dataTextField is posted to the server when the AutoComplete is positioned inside of a form element (just like a normal input). For your case the AutoComplete text will be posted using the **search** name.

If you want to send the underlying dataValueField (which is actually never used by the AutoComplete widget) you should use the [ComboBox](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/combobox/remotedatasource.html) widget.

Comment: Hi Pechka, You are right, that what i want to achieve. I found something like: string searchValue = Request.Params["filter[filters][0][value]"]; I just need to find out how to used it. Please let me know if you come across with this?